# How to call jobFinished from IntentService

Tags: android, job-scheduling

I trigger inside my JobService a IntentService which encapsulate simple tasks. How should i call jobFinished( param, false ) after my IntentService has finished and to tell the JobService he is done? Should i bind the JobService and call it directly or exist a better solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Callback to jobservice from intentservcie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647733/callback-to-jobservice-from-intentservcie)

Comment: @EugenPechanec I mean with task no AsyncTask. Just a task.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47875542/7292819)

Comment: @Eugen Pechanec don't mislead! JobService runs on UI thread. You should consider starting a worker thread to do some time consuming task, in this case onStartJob() should return true and you must call jobFinished() when you worker thread is done. (if you do a quick task on UI thread you don't have to start a worker thread and no need in calling jobFinished())